# Writing large amount of data using Akka in more efficient way

Tags: performance, scala, akka

I've implemented Scala Akka application that streams 4 different types of data from biomodule sensor (ECG, EEG, Breath and general data). These data (timestamp and value) are typically stored in 4 different CSV files. However, sometimes I have to store each sample in two different files with different timestamps, so application is writing in 8 different CSV files at the same time. 
Initially I've implemented one Akka actor that is responsible for persisting data, which receive path to the file in which to write data, timestamp and value. However, this was a bottleneck, since a number of samples that I need to store is large (e.g. one ECG sample is received each 4ms). As a result, this actor had finished recording in very short experiment 1-2 minutes after experiment is over.

I've also tried with 4 actors for 4 different message types, with the idea to distribute work. I didn't notice significant improvement in performances.

I'm wondering if someone has an idea how to improve the performance. Is it better to use one actor for storing files, few actors or it is most efficient if I have one actor for each file? Or maybe, it doesn't make any difference? Could I improve my code for storing data?

This is my method responsible for storing data:

```
  def processValue(sample: WaveformValue): Unit ={
      val csvfilewriter=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sample.filepath,true)))
      csvfilewriter.append(sample.timestamp.toString)
      csvfilewriter.append(",")
      csvfilewriter.append(sample.value.toString)
      csvfilewriter.append("\r\n")
      csvfilewriter.flush()
      csvfilewriter.close()
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your bottleneck is I/O -- disk access.  It looks like you are opening, writing to, and closing a file for each sample, which is very expensive.  I would suggest:

1. Open each file just once, and close it at the end of all processing.  You might need to store the file in a member variable, or if you have have an arbitrary collection of files then store them in a map in a member variable.
2. Don't flush after every sample write.
3. Use buffered writes for each file writer.  This avoids flushing data to the filesystem with every write, which involves a system call and waiting for the data to be written to disk.  I see that you're already doing this, but the benefit is lost since you are flushing/closing the file after each sample anyway.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Your suggestions totally makes sense to me. I'll redesign application as you suggested.